# Remedy8.1 (ITSM) - Get details of an Incident using Incident Number

Tags: java, web-services, axis, remedy

I'm using the below code to get the details of an incident in remedy 8.1(ITSM) but its throwing an error. When testing the WSDL via SOAP, I could able to fetch the details of the same Incident. Please help me out.

**Code:**

```
    StringHolder assigned_Group = null;
    StringHolder assigned_Group_Shift_Name = null;
    StringHolder assigned_Support_Company = null;
    StringHolder assigned_Support_Organization = null;
    StringHolder assignee = null;
    StringHolder categorization_Tier_1 = null;
    StringHolder categorization_Tier_2 = null;
    StringHolder categorization_Tier_3 = null;
    StringHolder city = null;
    StringHolder closure_Manufacturer = null;
    StringHolder closure_Product_Category_Tier1 = null;
    StringHolder closure_Product_Category_Tier2 = null;
    StringHolder closure_Product_Category_Tier3 = null;
    StringHolder closure_Product_Model_Version = null;
    StringHolder closure_Product_Name = null;
    StringHolder company = null;
    StringHolder contact_Company = null;
    HPD_IncidentInterface_WS.holders.Contact_SensitivityTypeHolder contact_Sensitivity = null;
    StringHolder country = null;
    StringHolder department = null;
    StringHolder summary = null;
    StringHolder notes = null;
    StringHolder first_Name = null;
    HPD_IncidentInterface_WS.holders.ImpactTypeHolder impact = null;
    StringHolder last_Name = null;
    StringHolder manufacturer = null;
    StringHolder middle_Initial = null;
    StringHolder organization = null;
    StringHolder phone_Number = null;
    HPD_IncidentInterface_WS.holders.PriorityTypeHolder priority = null;
    IntHolder priority_Weight = null;
    StringHolder product_Categorization_Tier_1 = null;
    StringHolder product_Categorization_Tier_2 = null;
    StringHolder product_Categorization_Tier_3 = null;
    StringHolder product_Model_Version = null;
    StringHolder product_Name = null;
    StringHolder region = null;
    HPD_IncidentInterface_WS.holders.Reported_SourceTypeHolder reported_Source = null;
    StringHolder resolution = null;
    StringHolder resolution_Category = null;
    StringHolder resolution_Category_Tier_2 = null;
    StringHolder resolution_Category_Tier_3 = null;
    HPD_IncidentInterface_WS.holders.Service_TypeTypeHolder service_Type = null;
    StringHolder site = null;
    StringHolder site_Group = null;
    HPD_IncidentInterface_WS.holders.StatusTypeHolder status = null;
    HPD_IncidentInterface_WS.holders.Status_ReasonTypeHolder status_Reason = null;
    HPD_IncidentInterface_WS.holders.UrgencyTypeHolder urgency = null;
    HPD_IncidentInterface_WS.holders.VIPTypeHolder VIP = null;
    StringHolder serviceCI = null;
    StringHolder serviceCI_ReconID = null;
    StringHolder HPD_CI = null;
    StringHolder HPD_CI_ReconID = null;
    StringHolder HPD_CI_FormName = null;
    StringHolder z1D_CI_FormName = null;

    HPD_IncidentInterface_WSPortTypePortTypeProxy objPort = new HPD_IncidentInterface_WSPortTypePortTypeProxy();        
    HPD_IncidentInterface_WSPortTypeSoapBindingStub objStub = new HPD_IncidentInterface_WSPortTypeSoapBindingStub();

    try {
        objStub.setUsername("admin");
        objStub.setPassword("pass");

        objPort.helpDesk_Query_Service("INC509526", assigned_Group, assigned_Group_Shift_Name, assigned_Support_Company, assigned_Support_Organization, assignee, categorization_Tier_1, categorization_Tier_2, categorization_Tier_3, city, closure_Manufacturer, closure_Product_Category_Tier1, closure_Product_Category_Tier2, closure_Product_Category_Tier3, closure_Product_Model_Version, closure_Product_Name, company, contact_Company, contact_Sensitivity, country, department, summary, notes, first_Name, impact, last_Name, manufacturer, middle_Initial, organization, phone_Number, priority, priority_Weight, product_Categorization_Tier_1, product_Categorization_Tier_2, product_Categorization_Tier_3, product_Model_Version, product_Name, region, reported_Source, resolution, resolution_Category, resolution_Category_Tier_2, resolution_Category_Tier_3, service_Type, site, site_Group, status, status_Reason, urgency, VIP, serviceCI, serviceCI_ReconID, HPD_CI, HPD_CI_ReconID, HPD_CI_FormName, z1D_CI_FormName);

        System.out.println("status_Reason - "+status_Reason);
    } catch (RemoteException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

**Error:**

```
AxisFault
 faultCode: {http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/}Server.userException
 faultSubcode: 
 faultString: ERROR (302): Entry does not exist in database; 
 faultActor: 
 faultNode: 
 faultDetail: 
    {http://xml.apache.org/axis/}hostname:CWWAPP511D

ERROR (302): Entry does not exist in database; 
    at org.apache.axis.message.SOAPFaultBuilder.createFault(SOAPFaultBuilder.java:222)
    at org.apache.axis.message.SOAPFaultBuilder.endElement(SOAPFaultBuilder.java:129)
    at org.apache.axis.encoding.DeserializationContext.endElement(DeserializationContext.java:1087)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.endElement(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanEndElement(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl$FragmentContentDriver.next(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl.next(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.next(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanDocument(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XMLParser.parse(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.parse(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.SAXParserImpl$JAXPSAXParser.parse(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.SAXParserImpl.parse(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.axis.encoding.DeserializationContext.parse(DeserializationContext.java:227)
    at org.apache.axis.SOAPPart.getAsSOAPEnvelope(SOAPPart.java:696)
    at org.apache.axis.Message.getSOAPEnvelope(Message.java:435)
    at org.apache.axis.handlers.soap.MustUnderstandChecker.invoke(MustUnderstandChecker.java:62)
    at org.apache.axis.client.AxisClient.invoke(AxisClient.java:206)
    at org.apache.axis.client.Call.invokeEngine(Call.java:2784)
    at org.apache.axis.client.Call.invoke(Call.java:2767)
    at org.apache.axis.client.Call.invoke(Call.java:2443)
    at org.apache.axis.client.Call.invoke(Call.java:2366)
    at org.apache.axis.client.Call.invoke(Call.java:1812)
    at HPD_IncidentInterface_WS.HPD_IncidentInterface_WSPortTypeSoapBindingStub.helpDesk_Query_Service(HPD_IncidentInterface_WSPortTypeSoapBindingStub.java:514)
    at HPD_IncidentInterface_WS.HPD_IncidentInterface_WSPortTypePortTypeProxy.helpDesk_Query_Service(HPD_IncidentInterface_WSPortTypePortTypeProxy.java:50)
    at HPD_IncidentInterface_WS.ITSMGetTicket.main(ITSMGetTicket.java:77)
```

Comment: If I understand your question correctly, you are trying to setup a SOAP client. The easiest way to do this is to generate all the client stub code through maven (http://www.coding.ractoc.com/soap-webservices-with-maven-part-5/). This way, you don't have to do any of that nasty stuff yourself since it is complex and error prone.

Answer (score 0):

Your request ID is too short  "INC509526"  is missing a load of zeros. should be "INC00000509526".

All Remedy request IDs are 14 characters long, hence your 302 - entry does not exist.